# Sustituir alt gr + , y alt gr + . por < y >

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de crear un script en Python que me permita, cuando presione la combinación de teclas **altGr** + **,** me escriba **<** y cuando haga la combinación **alt gr** + **.** me escriba **>**.
Cuando digo escribir no me refiero a que me lo imprima por pantalla sino que fuera como si yo hubiera pulsado dicha tecla.
El código que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
import keyboard

def register_hotkeys():
    def on_hotkey(action):
        keyboard.write(action)

    keyboard.add_hotkey('alt gr + .', lambda: on_hotkey(">"))

    keyboard.add_hotkey('alt gr + comma', lambda: on_hotkey("<"))

    keyboard.wait('esc')

register_hotkeys()
```

Este código cumple con el objetivo, pero el problema que no consigo arreglar es que si presiono **alt gr** y mantengo presionado el **.** o la **,** en vez de hacerme <<<<< o >>>>> me hace <,<,<,<,<,<,<,< o >.>.>.>.>.> además de que si hago **alt gr ,** y sin soltar **alt gr** presiono el **.** no me hace <> sino que me hace <.> cuando lo que busco sería los primeros casos (<<<<<, >>>>> y <>).

Comment: Prueba agregando `supress=True` https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard?tab=readme-ov-file#keyboard.add_hotkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de añadir el parámetro supress = True como alguien dijo en comentarios, te dejo la parte del código que deberias modificar.

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('.', lambda: on_hotkey(">"), suppress=True)
keyboard.add_hotkey(',', lambda: on_hotkey("<"), suppress=True)
```

Esto evitará que la tecla original se escriba, y en su lugar se escribirá la acción que has definido.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!. La única pega que le veo es que cuando por ejemplo presiono la tecla altgr y la suelto (sin presionar otra), como que el teclado me cambia el funcionamiento a atajos de teclado. Por ejemplo presiono la e y en vez de una e sale un € si presiono otra tecla se abre el menu de guardar el fichero, etc