# se pueden ejecutar comando de teclado como ctrl+c y ctrl+v de forma asíncrona en python

Tags: python, asincronismo

tengo un programa que es asíncrono con interfaz y puede ejecutar comandos de teclado pero mi duda es si esos comandos se pueden ejecutar de igual forma asincronos

por ejemplo:

yo ejecuto el programa y copia un texto con el ctrl+c y los pega con ctrl+v en un bloc de notas pero para que esto se pueda hacer no puedo usar la computadora hasta que se termine de ejecutar, quiero poder usar el equipo sin que se interrumpa el proceso y tampoco que se interrumpan los comandos de teclado, es posible?

Comment: Quieres algo como lo que hace en esta pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/616668/169744